# Why is UuX used as a symbol for unnamed elements on the periodic table?

Tags: nomenclature, elements, periodic-table, history-of-chemistry

Until recently, the last few elements on the periodic table had the chemical symbols (now they have formal chemical symbols!):

Uub, Uut, Uuq, Uup, Uuh, Uus, and Uuo

Why did they have these temporary symbols? Why the letter U? Is there any reasoning behind the third letter? Why not:

Uua, Uub, Uuc, Uud, Uue, etc...

I was just wondering some of the history of nomenclature and the thought process behind this specific nomenclature.

Comment: Related: [Why is a temporary name given to an element with an atomic number above 100?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/16029/4945)

Comment: Technically, only one element (119) still uses Uux (specifically, Uue). All others from 110-118 are experimentally known and have assumed proper names, and for 120 or more the second letter becomes different. See ringo's answer for more details..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In 1978, the IUPAC Commission on the Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry decided that it would be necessary to have a systematic naming for the elements with atomic number greater than 100, even for those which had not been discovered. The recommendations are as follows:

> 1. The name is derived directly from the atomic number of the element using
>      the following numerical roots:
>
> $$\require{enclose}
> \small
> \begin{array}{lcc}
> \hline
> \text{Number} & \text{Latin Word} & \text{Greek Word} & \text{IUPAC Nomenclature} \\
> \hline
> \text{0} & \enclose{circle}{\text{nihil}} & \text{mēdén} & \text{nil} \\
> \text{1} & \enclose{circle}{\text{ūnus}} & \text{en} & \text{un} \\
> \text{2} & \enclose{circle}{\text{duo}} & \enclose{circle}{\text{dúō}} & \text{bi } \\
> \text{3} & \text{trēs} & \enclose{circle}{\text{tria}} & \text{tri} \\
> \text{4} & \enclose{circle}{\text{quattuor}} & \text{téttara} & \text{quad} \\
> \text{5} & \text{quīnque} & \enclose{circle}{\text{pénte}} & \text{pent} \\
> \text{6} & \text{sex} & \enclose{circle}{\text{héx}} & \text{hex} \\
> \text{7} & \enclose{circle}{\text{septem}} & \text{heptá} & \text{sept} \\
> \text{8} & \enclose{circle}{\text{octō}} & \enclose{circle}{\text{oktṓ}} & \text{oct} \\
> \text{9} & \text{novem} & \enclose{circle}{\text{ennéa}} & \text{enn} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> 2. The roots are put together in the order of the digits which make up the
>      atomic number and terminated by 'ium' to spell out the name. The final
>      'n' of 'enn' is elided when it occurs before 'nil', and the final 'i' of
>      'bi' and of 'tn' when it occurs before 'ium'.
> 3. The symbol of the element is composed of the initial letters of the
>      numerical roots which make up the name.
> 4. The root 'un' is pronounced with a long 'u', to rhyme with 'moon'.
>      In the element names each root is to be pronounced separately.$^{[1]}$

Though not in the original text, I went ahead and added the words from which the IUPAC names were derived. Though not obvious, bi- comes directly from di-, which is a result of duo, found in both languages.

---

<sub>$^{[1]}$ [Recommendations for the Naming of Elements of Atomic Numbers Greater than 100, Pure Appl. Chem., Vol. 51, No. 2, (1979) 381-384](https://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/1979/pdf/5102x0381.pdf).</sub>